# Exponent of a group and abelian groups

Tags: group-theory

Is there exist an abelian group $G$, s.t the following conditions hold:

1. $|G|=32$
2. $exp(G)=4$
3. $[G:G^2]=4$

While $G^2=\left\{g^2|g\in G\right\}$ (it is an abelian subgroup of $G$) and $exp(G)$ is the least common multiple of the orders of all elements of $G$.

My thoughts and attempts:
I first tried to disprove it by looking for contradictions,
If $|G|=32$, and $[G:G^2]=4$ it holds that $|G^2|=8$, and since $exp(G)=4$, then $exp(G^2)=2$, meaning **if** there exist such a group, then all the $G^2$ elements are of order $2$. nothing impossible here.
So I then tried to look for the obvious: $G=\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_4\times\mathbb{Z}_4$, so $|G|=32$, and $exp(G)=4$, but the third condition won't hold, since $G^2=2\mathbb{Z}_2\times2\mathbb{Z}_4\times2\mathbb{Z}_4$ which has $4$ elements in it.
I also tried to consider multiplicative groups of integers modulo n, but couldn't find anything, and now, again, I'm starting to think there is no such $G$.

Any ideas/tips?

Comment: If you know the classification theorem of finite abelian groups, your comments above very nearly give you a proof.

Comment: There is I think such a G if you remove the condition that G be abelian though.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing it right. There are only a few possibilities for an abelian group of order $32,$ just go through them all one by one (but of course, having exponent be $4$ means that the biggest cyclic factor is of order $4,$ which really cuts things down, since there are either one or two such factors, and the rest are $\mathbb{Z}/2 \mathbb{Z}$-s.

Comment: Thank you. I read about classification theorem of finite abelian groups, and found out there are only two **potential** groups.
when I checked each one of them, I realized that such a group does not exist. :)